# Short Date that is given from a SQL data table shows with time and full details

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, date, gridview, datatable

I have a data table in my SQL that dates stored in a column as: Submit Date - and date Data Type Like:
`2014/12/02` but when a get this table and put it into a gridview the Submit Date column become like :

```
AM 12:00:00 '2014/12/02'
```

so how can i remove the time first part and just get the date in gridview?

The column is like this:

```
 <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="SubmitDate" HeaderText="SubDate">
      <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblSubmitDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SubmitDate")%>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a databound column use the attribute DataFormatString to remove the time.

Comment: replace your eval() for this `Text='<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("SubmitDate")).ToShortDateString()%>'`

Comment: it solved; but the format of date is like dd/mm/yy. how can i turn it to yy/mm/dd?

Comment: replace `ToShortDateString()` to ToString("yy/MM/dd"), here is the full documentation about formatting the date to a string https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx, don't forget to mark as answered if your problem is solved.